# analytics.logEvent() doesn't work

Tags: logging, lua, coronasdk

I want to add logs to my application. This is my code:

```
local analytics = require "analytics"
analytics.init("X6YPFYT6NPJYF5xxxxxx")
analytics.logEvent("Game is started!")
```

I run it on device, but I don't see any data or sessions in flurry.com site.
What does I miss here? Did somebody tried to use corona "analytics" module?

What are other ways to add logs ob Corona SDK (I familiar only with sending tcp-packets and with output redirection to xCode console)

Answer (score 2):

I received an answer in Corona forum:
it works only on device, and it  takes a day to see analytics results on the site.